# check if ALL variables are in one list

Tags: python, dictionary

**Set-up**

I have a dictionary variable `tags_dict`.

I have an if condition that looks like,

```
    if 'seat_height_min' in tags_dict and 'seat_height_max' in tags_dict and 'material_wheels' in tags_dict:
        #do something
```

---

**Question**

How do I write this simpler?

I'd love to do something along the lines of,

```
if all('seat_height_min','seat_height_max','material_wheels') in tags_dict:
    # do something
```

but this doesn't work.

Is there a function that does something like the above?

Comment: Maybe something like `if all([x in tags_dict for x in ['seat_height_min', 'seat_height_max', 'material_wheels']]):` Though be warned that this won't perform any short circuiting if any of the boolean expressions are false

Comment: @byxor Omit the outer `[]`, just `all(x in ...)` is more efficient, and then it *will* short-circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
all([x in d for x in ['a','b','c']])
```

the code above returns true

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through a list of your strings as below

```
if all(i in d for i in ['seat_height_min','seat_height_max','material_wheels']):
  #do something
```